# Merging overlapping multiband rasters in QGIS - massive files?

Tags: qgis, raster, merge, overlapping-rasters

What is the best way to do this? I have two images that overlap about 20%, and they are 4 bands each. Same satellite provider, resolution, etc. so there's no apparent issue with alignment. Each file is a little under 1.5 Gb.

My method was was to build a VRT where I selected each of the two overlapping layers, unchecked `place each input file into a separate band` (I don't understand what this does).

Then I used GDAL translate to convert the VRT back into a GeoTIFF. After I did this, the file grew to 6.5 Gb. How is that possible if each separate file was < 1.5 Gb? All other parameters were left to default in QGIS.

Comment: What compression are you using? How are they overlapping, are the output not rectangular, nodata also consume space

Comment: I'm not using any compression, just GDAL translate as it appears in QGIS. I'm not sure about your other point - all rasters are rectangular? There are some new NoData cells, but relatively very new ones.

Comment: Try selecting 'High compression' under Additional creation options. I mean if they overlap [like this](https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/cdn-uploads/rectanglesOverlap.png) it is going to consume more space than if they overlap like the [left image here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/356913937/figure/fig4/AS:1099332317126716@1639112657810/Two-ways-of-overlapping-two-rectangles-with-exactly-the-same-IOU-value.png)

Comment: Check also what compression, if any, is used in the source images.